# Calculate $x=\frac{1}{a}$ indirectly

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

For a given constant like $a \ne 0$, we are asked to calculate $\frac{1}{a}$ indirectly. **The question also asks to determine the values of $x_0$ for which the sequence converges.**

Note:
We have learned fixed-point iteration, False position, Newton, Aitken, Steffenson methods. I think that for this question, it's enough to provide a function with root $\frac{1}{a}$. So, is $g(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{a}+x}{2}$ good? If yes, how should I answer the second part of the question? I mean, How should I determine a bound for $x_0$ such that this bound, guarantees the sequence's convergence?

Note 2: The first part of my question is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550177/using-newtons-method-calculate-frac1-sqrta-without-division).

Note 3: For example, if you're using fixed-point iteration method, you should provide $g(x)$ before seeing $a$, and guarantee that it works for every arbitrary $a$ that you will be given.

Note 4: You can use whatever you want, But you should avoid the direct division $\frac{1}{a}$. Other divisions can be used.

Comment: Calculate it to be ... what, exactly?  $\frac 1a$ is ... $\frac 1a$.  What else needs to be be said?  I'd find the expression $\frac 1a$ to be the *most* accurate and explicit expression possible.  Far preferable than any decimal or convergent sequence approximation.  And determine the of values of $x_0$ for which *what* sequence converges?  What the *heck* are you talking about and what is your question actually?

Comment: @fleablood Please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550177/using-newtons-method-calculate-frac1-sqrta-without-division and hopefully, you'll get what I mean :)

Comment: I guess the problem is something like: "I give you $a$, you aproximate the value of $\tfrac 1 a$ but do not make any division." But then... your $g(x)$ won't work since you would have to calculate $\tfrac 1 a$ in order to make the iterations.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum Yes, you're right!

Comment: Question: What does "without division" mean? For instance, (assuming $a$ is positive) I could look for the largest number with a single non-zero digit $x_1$ such that $x_1a\leq 1$. Then I could look at the largest single digit that I can add to $x_1$ to make $x_2$ with two non-zero digits such that $x_2a\leq 1$. And suddenly we have the standard long-division algorithm most people learn in school, even though all I've actually done is addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Arthur In my question, It means you can calculate whatever you want, But assume you don't have the tools to calculate $\frac{1}{a}$ directly. So, you should use other functions to approximate it :)

Comment: This is easy to do with Newton's method. However, you need a good initial approximation $x_0$ or it won't converge. Assuming WLOG that $0<a$, then for $a<1$ you can use $x_0=1$. But getting a usable $x_0$ for $a>1$ is problematic if you aren't permitted _any_ kind of division since in that case $x_0$ _must_ be $<=\frac{1}{a}$ to achieve convergence, but if $x_0$ is too small convergence is glacially slow.

Comment: @PM2Ring not "any kind of division", just $\frac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration given by LutzL can be derived using Newton's method. I suppose it won't hurt to give that derivation (which is what I was going to do anyway before I saw LutzL's answer).

To find the reciprocal of $a$ using Newton's method, let 
$$y = x^{-1}$$
then
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -x^{-2}$$
Let $$\Delta y = a - y = a - x^{-1}$$
Now let
$$\Delta x = \frac{\Delta y}{dy/dx}$$
thus
$$\Delta x = \frac{a - x^{-1}}{-x^{-2}}$$
or
$$\Delta x = x - a x^2$$
Hence a better approximation for $x$ is
$$x + \Delta x = 2x - a x^2$$

Of course, we need to find a suitable initial $x$ or we won't get convergence. As I mentioned in the comments, $x_0=1$ will work for $0 < a \le 1$, but it's faster if we start with an $x_0$ that's closer to $\frac{1}{a}$, although $x_0$ does need to be $\le \frac{1}{a}$.

A simple way to find a suitable $x_0$ is to find a nearby binary power. We can do that by repeated doubling for $a<1$ and by repeated halving for $a>1$. FWIW, I didn't post this solution earlier, because I assumed that halving wasn't permitted.

---

How accurate does $x_0$ need to be? We want

$$x_{n+1} = x_n(2 - ax_n)$$
to converge. Using LutzL's notation, let $r_n = 1 - ax_n$ be the error term and hence $x_n = \frac1a(1 - r_n)$, so we want 
$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} |r_n| = 0$$

Now substituting that expression for $x_n$ in terms of $r_n$ into our iteration formula we get
$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1} & = x_n(2 - ax_n)\\
& = \frac1a(1 - r_n)(1 + r_n)\\
& = \frac1a(1 - r_n^2)\\ 
& = \frac1a(1 - r_{n+1})\\ 
\end{align}$$
That is, $r_{n+1}=r_n^2$, and since for convergence we want $r_{n+1} < |r_n|$ that implies that $|r_n| < 1$.

Thus
$$\begin{align}
-1 & < -r_0 < 1\\
0 & < 1-r_0 < 2\\
0 & < ax_0 < 2\\
\end{align}$$

But we can easily do a little better than that. In my algorithm, when $a < 1$ we start with $x = 1$ and keep doubling $x$ while $ax < \frac12$, so when that loop stops, $ax \ge \frac12$. But on the previous loop $x$ had half that value, so $\frac12ax<\frac12$, in other words,

$$\begin{align}
\frac12 & \le ax < 1\\
-1 & < -ax \le -\frac12\\
0 & < 1-ax \le \frac12\\
0 & < r \le \frac12\\
\end{align}$$

Similarly, when $a \ge 1$ we start with $x = 1$ and keep halving $x$ while $ax > 1$, so when that loop stops, $ax \le 1$. But on the previous loop $x$ had double that value, so $2ax > 1$, in other words,

$$\begin{align}
\frac12 & < ax \le 1\\
-1 & \le -ax < -\frac12\\
0 & \le 1-ax < \frac12\\
0 & \le r < \frac12\\
\end{align}$$

---

Here's some Python code that illustrates this algorithm. (This code will run correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3). It could be written more compactly, but I've tried to avoid "Pythonisms" to make the algorithm more readable for those not familiar with Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

def recip(a):
    ''' Find the reciprocal of a without doing 1 / a '''
    if a == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError

    # Convert negative a to positive
    if a < 0:
        sign = -1
        a = -a
    else:
        sign = 1

    #Find a good initial approximation
    x = 1
    if a < 1:
        while a * x < 0.5:
            x = x * 2
    else:
        while a * x > 1:
            x = x * 0.5

    # Improve the approximation with Newton's method
    while True:
        d = x - a * x * x
        x = x + d
        #print(x, d, a * x)
        if abs(d) < 1e-15:
            break

    return sign * x

# Test

data = (-3, -0.1, 0.0001, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 17, 163) 
for a in data:
    x = recip(a)
    print(a, x, a * x)
```

**output**

```
-3 -0.3333333333333333 1.0
-0.1 -10.0 1.0
0.0001 10000.0 1.0
0.2 5.0 1.0
0.8 1.25 1.0
1 1 1
1.5 0.6666666666666666 1.0
2 0.5 1.0
5 0.2 1.0
17 0.058823529411764705 1.0
163 0.006134969325153374 1.0
```

FWIW, this algorithm isn't merely an answer to a frivolous puzzle. It has been used to calculate reciprocals and hence quotients when performing arbitrary precision arithmetic, in conjunction with the Fast Fourier Transform for performing the multiplications.

Thanks to LutzL for his suggestions to improve the above code.

Comment: You can handle the negative case without explicitly remembering the sign using one recursive call, ` if a<0: return -recip(-a);`. You could also "optimize" the power-2 loops by using `a*x<0.4` resp. `a*>1.6`. Avoid explicit division by changing `x/2` to `0.5*x`.

Comment: Good points, @LutzL, although I generally prefer to avoid recursion in Python unless it's necessary: Python doesn't optimize tail calls.

Comment: It's a script language. But recursion depth 1 is always harmless. One has to take care when the depth becomes variable.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm so dumb... But I still don't understand how $0.4$ and $1.6$ got involved in the solution...

Comment: @PaoloMolina In the original version of my script I used 0.5 & 1 instead of 0.4 and 1.6, but LutzLs answer mentions in the last paragraph of his answer that the initial error needs to be smaller than 1 in absolute value which can be achieved by using $x_0=2^m$ where $2^ma$ is in the interval $[\frac23,\frac43]$.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why should $2^m a $ be in that interval?

Comment: @PaoloMolina I'm not quite sure why LutzL suggested that interval. And I just noticed that $[\frac23,\frac43]$ isn't consistent with his $[0.4, 1.6]$. So I've reverted my code to the previous bounds, which I believe are adequate to ensure that $|1-ax_0| < 1$, which is all we need to guarantee that the algorithm converges. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok, 2 questions: 1. what bound are u suggesting for $x_0$? 2. Why exactly does this bound guarantee the convergence of $g(x_n)$? (Please write simple things... That way i won't get confused... Thanks)

Comment: You can guarantee that for any interval $[c,d]$ with $d=2c$ that one of the numbers $2^ma$ falls inside that interval. To make the bounds symmetric to $1$ solve $d-1=1-c$ to get $[2/3,4/3]$. You can do the same with powers of $4$ for less tries, then $d=4c$ and together with the symmetry you get that one of the $4^ma$ is inside $[0.4,1.6]$.

Comment: @LutzL Ah! I get the first one, $[2/3,4/3]$ gives us $|r|<\frac13$, but I don't get the second, since $[2/5,8/5]\implies-\frac35\le r \le \frac75$, but we need $|r|<1$.

Comment: $8/5-1=8/5-5/5=3/5$ so $|r|<0.6$.

Comment: @LutzL Oops! That's right. I somehow lost a minus sign. It's getting late here. :) $[2/5,8/5]\implies-\frac35\le r \le \frac35$

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n$ is some approximation to the inverse, then $r_n=1-ax_n$ is small. As $ax_n=1-r_n$, so is $$ax_n(1+r_n)=1-r_n^2$$ by binomial theorems. As $r_n^2$ is a smaller error, $$x_{n+1}=x_n(1+r_n)=x_n(2-ax_n)=g(x_n)$$ is a better approximation.

You can get this method as Newton method for $$f(x)=\frac1x-a$$ or as per Arthur  using the geometric sequence with the identity $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\prod_{n=0}^\infty(1+x^{2^n}).$$ The only condition is that the initial error needs to be smaller than $1$ in absolute value which can be achieved by finding the dyadic power $x_0=2^m$ so that $2^ma\in [\frac23,\frac43]$ or $[0.4,1.6]$. This you can do by extracting the floating point exponent using `frexp` or similar.

Comment: Can you please simplify what you said? So, Which $g$ do you recommend to use?

Comment: @PaoloMolina $g(x_n)$ is simply $x_n(2-ax_n)$, which is the Newton's method approximation.

Comment: @PaoloMolina : Did you read my last paragraph? The answer was always there.

Comment: I don't understand how did you find that bound for $2^m$ ... What is $frexp$?

Comment: Search for an interval symmetric around $1$ so that the upper bound is twice or 4 times the lower bound. `frexp` is a helper function that separates the information contained in a floating point number. One can do the same using bit manipulations with heavy recasting. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/frexp/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change that $g(x)$ in order to respect the "spirit" of the problem. In any case, if you want to analyze convergence, then you have this result: if $g \in C^1\big([a,b]\big)$, $g\big([a,b]\big)\subset [a,b]$ and $g'(x)\leq K<1$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then for every $x_0 \in [a,b]$ the recurrence
$$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$$
converges to the only fixed point of $g$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: In fact, you have $|x^*-x_n|\leq (b-a) K^n$, if $x^*$ is the fixed point.

Comment: Thanks... But my problem is finding that $g$ ...

Comment: Yeah... it does not come to me an obvious answer. I'll probably keep thinking.

Comment: For instance, $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2-ax}$ does have $\tfrac 1 a$ as a fixed point for any $a>0$ (add a minus sign in front for $a<0$). Anyway... I haven't checked if it generates a convergent sequence and I don't know either if you're allowed to use a square root (after all, we're avoiding division!).

Comment: Using square root isn't prohibited :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution: For $-1<x<1$, we have $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$Insert $x=1-a$, and you have an approximation valid for $0<a<2$ that you can get as accurate as you'd like by just adding more terms. Of course, if $-2<a<0$, you can calculate $\frac1{-a}$ instead the same way, and just change the sign afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, sir, But there is no guarantee that $a$ is bounded like that... What if $a \gt 2$?

Comment: That is why I called it a partial solution. It does not solve your entire problem, but I wanted it written down, and I think a bit too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solving $f(x)=0$ where
$$
f(x)=\frac1x-a
$$
using Newton's Method gives the iteration
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}
&=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\\
&=x_n-\frac{\frac1{x_n}-a}{-\frac1{x_n^2}}\\
&=x_n+x_n-ax_n^2
\end{align}
$$
that is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x_{n+1}=2x_n-ax_n^2}
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-\frac1a
&=2x_n-ax_n^2-\frac1a\\
&=-a\left(x_n-\frac1a\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
the iteration is a contraction if $|ax_n-1|\lt1$.

> A good choice is $x_0=10^k$ so that $0.1\lt ax_0\le1$.

Once it gets going, each iteration should about double the number of digits of accuracy.

---

**Example**

Find $\frac1{32}$: Let $a=32$ and $x_0=0.01$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
n&x_n\\\hline
0&0.01\\
1&0.0168\\
2&0.02456832\\
3&0.0298213648760832\\
4&0.031184688053846759344\\
5&0.031249863499190069638\\
6&0.031249999999403760924\\
7&0.031250000000000000000\\
8&0.031250000000000000000
\end{array}
$$

Comment: LutzL makes the suggestion of Newton's method and PM 2Ring implements it in code. I hope my answer shows a more theoretical side of things. Also, the suggestion of the starting $x_0$ might be useful.

Comment: I changed the value for $x_0$ to $\frac1{10^k}$ since it is easier to compute in base $10$.